# repeating the first line just once ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a mongodb collection with this parameters:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("59c265235e21f8a8b7d75b23"),
"email": "tworsnipi@bbc.co.uk",
"password": "PlPEVQpAt",
"company_name": "Oyope",
"site": "noaa.gov",
"description": "lorem id ligula suspendisse ornare",
"ads": [{
    "id": 19,
    "users_apply": [],
    "email": "bmenguyi@utexas.edu",
    "phone": "(847) 2671999",
    "location": {
        "longtitude": -88.0549221,
        "latitude": 42.1165506
    },
    "status": "open",
    "skills": ["Financial Analysis"],
    "scope": "half"
  }]
}
```

I would like to show the company_name, and all the elements that are in the array "ads".

for that I have done this:

```
            <tr ng-repeat="ad in pubJobs2 | filter:{company_name: search.company_name} | limitTo : 10 : begin()">
                <td><a ng-click="loadJob(ad.company_name)">{{ad.company_name}}</a></td>
                <td>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>email</td>
                            <td>Phone</td>                            
                            <td>location</td>
                            <td>description</td>
                            <td>scope</td>
                            <td>status</td>
                            <td>skills</td>
                            <td></td>                                
                        </tr>

                        <tr ng-repeat="adv in ad.ads | filter:{email: search.email, scope: search.scope} ">
                            <td>{{adv.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{adv.phone}}</td>
                            <td>{{adv.location}}</td>
                            <td>{{adv.description}}</td>
                            <td>{{adv.scope}}</td>
                            <td>{{adv.status}}</td>
                            <td>{{adv.skills}}</td>
                            <td><button class="button" ng-click="applyJob(adv.id)">Apply</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

            </tr>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

the problem is that the titles are repeating too.
How could I avoid it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean `titles` there is no attribute like that, also the invalid/expected output could be useful for this question

Comment: I guess , here titles you are referring to column headings like email, phone etc.... right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't using your data, but this shows how you can use the (often misused) `ngInit` directive to grab a reference to the previous record in an `ngRepeat`. As you can see, I simply suppress the category unless it has changed from the previous record.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WtO3AzWokzpbG5YIPSYP?p=preview

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="food in $ctrl.data" ng-init="prevFood = $ctrl.data[$index-1]">
    <td>{{prevFood.category !== food.category ? food.category : '&nbsp;'}}</td>
    <td>{{food.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```